# Azure Container Web App Giving ;( Application Error

Tags: containers, azure-container-apps

Just starting to learn Docker Containers. Started by trying to get a simple web app published. I only created the project and published it to Azure. Everything is fine until the web app runs. I get :( Application Error. I read someplace to expose 8080, but that didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated.